# Finding BST's height non-recursively?

Tags: binary-search-tree

This is a recursive method for finding the height, but i have a very large number of nodes in my binary search tree, and i want to find the height of the tree as well as assign the height to each individual sub-tree. So the recursive method throws stackoverflow exception, how do i do this non-recursively and without using stack?

```
private int FindHeight(TreeNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            node.Height = 1 + Math.Max(FindHeight(node.Left), FindHeight(node.Right));
            return node.Height;
        }
    }
```

I believe i have to use post order traversal but without stack?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this method, and it does return the correct height but it assigns each node with its depth not height.

```
 public void FindHeight()
    {
        int maxHeight = 0;
        Queue<TreeNode> Q = new Queue<TreeNode>();
        TreeNode node;
        Q.Enqueue(Root);
        while (Q.Count != 0)
        {
            node = Q.Dequeue();
            int nodeHeight = node.Height;
            if (node.Left != null)
            {
                node.Left.Height = nodeHeight + 1;
                Q.Enqueue(node.Left);
            }
            if (node.Right != null)
            {
                node.Right.Height = nodeHeight + 1;
                Q.Enqueue(node.Right);
            }
            if (nodeHeight > maxHeight)
            {
                maxHeight = nodeHeight;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(maxHeight);
    }
```